# Config with one customizable parameter that impact other config parameters

Tags: python

I have a config.py file, containing paths and other constant values :

```
WORKING_PATH = Path(__file__).resolve().parent

size = 160
order = 4

experiment_dir = WORKING_PATH / 'data/experiment'

...
```

Now this was easy to import in my main script, and just access the values with `config.experiment_dir` for example.

But I want to update the code and make the `WORKING_PATH` customizable, with an input argument taken from the cli.
If I just overwrite the `WORKING_PATH` variable in my main function, the `experiment_dir` variable is already set to the default `WORKING_PATH`, so I have to find a better solution.

What is the best and cleanest way to handle this, while keeping it simple?

Also, the paths found in my config get referenced many times in different functions, so I want to avoid having to just pass the config every where as a parameter. I would like for it to be accessible everywhere, and would like to keep the same syntax as before (`config.experiment_dir` for example), so I don't have to change all the config access.

I guess I could just make the config into a class, with the `WORKING_PATH` as an customizable attribute, but I would have to make it `global` in my main function, to avoid having to pass it everywhere as a parameter. I am not sure it is a really clean solution. Or is there a way to do this using a static class, but with one variable that can be changed?

EDIT : I think I could just use the overwriting solution I had, but wrap the parameters that depend of `WORKING_PATH` in each their own function, such as :

```
def experiment_dir():
    return WORKING_PATH / 'data/experiment'
```

I will just have to adjust the code by adding () to all those references though. But in this way, the variables such as `experiment_dir` won't get set at the beginning of the program, and will check the WORKING_PATH each time it is referenced. Again, I am not sure how clean this is, since some parameters of the config will now be accessible as functions with a (), and some won't be using (), being plain variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global variables are not meant to be changed but you can using `global`, i would wrap all the variables that need to change in a class with some dynamic features.

```
import os

SIZE = 160
ORDER = 4

class CFP:

    cwd = None

    exp_dir = None
    exp_rel_path = 'data/experiment'

    def __init__(self, path=__file__, **kwargs):
        self.update_to(path, **kwargs)

    def update_to(self, fname, **kwargs):
        for k in kwargs:
            self.__dict__[k] = kwargs[k]

        if not os.path.isdir(fname):
            self.cwd = os.path.abspath(
                os.path.dirname(fname))
        else:
            self.cwd = os.path.abspath(fname)

        self.exp_dir = os.path.join(
            self.cwd, *self.pharsed_join(self.exp_rel_path)
        )
        self.__check_all()

    def __check_all(self):
        for p in self.__dict__:
            if 'rel' not in p:
                path = self.__dict__[p]
                if not os.path.exists(path):
                    raise FileExistsError(path)

    @staticmethod
    def pharsed_join(pstr):
        if '/' in pstr:
            return pstr.split('/')
        return [pstr]
```

```
from config_vars import *

config = CFP(exp_rel_path='files')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(config.exp_dir)
    config.update_to('./build', exp_rel_path='o-console')
    print(config.exp_dir)
```